# Multiple powershell scripts crashing at the same time using timer

Tags: powershell

I have 3 independent powershell scripts all called separately that all do very similar things.  A timer is setup in each to check CVS files every 5 minutes and display the results as an icon in the task bar in Windows.  They query different CSV files but the layout is similar as below:

```
//setup my variables
$poll_timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer($poll_interval * 1000 * 60)
$poll_timer.Start()

function check_CSV{
    query the CSV
    $Icon.Icon = $whichImage
...
} 
$poll = {
    check_CSV
} 
Register-ObjectEvent $poll_timer -EventName Elapsed -Action $poll
```

All works well and they run all day.  However, 2 or 3 times a week, they crash so the polling stops.  What I find weird though is that all 3 crash and stop polling.  Powershell still works if I run a different script, but these 3, which are all called independently, all crash at the same time.

I have put $ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue" at the top and it doesn't seem to make any difference.  I can't see why they crash, it just occasionally seems to hang whilst running the checking of the CSV.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your code using try catch `try{$poll = {
    check_CSV
}}catch{}`

Comment: No.  But I can do!

Comment: I would add some logging to confirm each step, but I suspect that the CSV files are inaccessible so now and then (e.g. because they being exported from ?Excel?). JPBlanc suggestion might indeed resolve such issue but your `SilentlyContinue` might also cause that you dealing with invalid data (empty or from a previous poll)...

Comment: if you are simply checking for a file ... have you tried using the built in method for handling that? [*grin*] this .... FileSystemWatcher Class (System.IO) | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2 ///// it can watch for a file using standard system resources and you won't have the PoSh instances running all the time since it can be used as a task trigger.

Comment: @JPBlanc Assigning a variable a scriptblock will never cause an exception.. the try/catch should wrap around the command call instead.

Comment: @ TheIncorrigible1 my mistake I just want to catch the check_CSV exception `$poll = {
   try{ check_CSV}catch{# Put the log}
} `

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I believe it was due to the independent Powershell scripts using the same Timer names.  So I used for example:

```
Register-ObjectEvent $poll_timer_script1 -EventName Elapsed -Action $poll_script1 
Register-ObjectEvent $poll_timer_script2 -EventName Elapsed -Action $poll_script2
```

I do not fully understand why this would help as they are separate scripts in separate files called independently but after a couple of weeks, I've not had a crash which would almost certainly have happened by now.